# Join two simple jquery conditions

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have made a php form wherein I would like to display a loading gif if certain conditions are met. Here is a readable psuedo-code/example of the logic I need to employ in jquery.

```
if (file_input_is_set && submit_button_is_clicked) {
   <div class="progress-bar">tada...loading_gif</div> 
  }
```

I have these two codes which work well individually. *First code* shows the loading gif when file input is set.

```
jQuery().on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function(e) {
```

*Second code* shows the loading gif when the form-submit-button is clicked.

```
jQuery("input[name='profile_submit']").click(function (e) {
```

Since I know almost nothing about jQuery, I need help to **put these events together**. Forgive me if my terminology is wrong. Here is what I have tried that do not work, it shows the loading gif even before I press the submit button. So I need a function which works like the php's `&&` operator, and I dont know how you do that in jquery.

```
jQuery().on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function(e) {
    jQuery("input[name='profile_submit']").click(function (e) {
    //jQuery('#submit-button').hide();
    jQuery('.progress-bar').fadeIn(1000);
    });
    });
```

Note: The reason you see a lot of `jQuery` in the code is due to wordpress ( in which the form is used) as it needs it to be in no-conflict mode.

---

> **Rephrased Question** ( with hint from @webkit) : How do I **also** check if
>   file_input_is_set/valid when submit event triggered ?

Comment: There's a difference between checking for conditions, and checking for events (change, click..) you can either delegate the events to one handler OR, when submit event triggers check also to see if input is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the last action, form submit. then check for existence of file in file input:

```
jQuery("input[name='profile_submit']").click(function (e) {
      if( jQuery('input[type="file"]').val() != '' ){
        jQuery('.progress-bar').fadeIn(1000);
      }
});
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nDNP5/

Comment: It works, YES. I had to flush the cache to see the changes. Sorry I didnot realize that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
jQuery("input[name='profile_submit']").click(function (e) {
    // check to see if file is valid
    if (jQuery('input[type="file"]').val() != "") {
        // load
        jQuery('.progress-bar').fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
```

Or this: (Only when file has been selected will you activate submit btn)

```
jQuery('input[type="file"]').on('change', function (e) {
    // check to see if file is valid
    if (jQuery('input[type="file"]').val() != "") {
        jQuery("input[name='profile_submit']").off().on('click', function () {
            jQuery('.progress-bar').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    } else {
        jQuery("input[name='profile_submit']").off()
    }
});
```